# JQuery slide area

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Does JQuery have the ability to create an area that scrolls? Like I have a small box and I need to show some check boxes but they don't all fit so I need a way to slide down the list.

Comment: Can you post some sample code? Are you setting the html by doing $('#box).html("html_code_for the box"); ? Or are you using any plugin?

Comment: the answer is yes, jQuery has this ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jquery to do that. Just use `overflow:scroll` in css in a fixed size div.

Sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/a4PHU/

If you want to set it with jquery, you can of course use

```
$('#a').css('overflow', 'scroll');
```